# Do I correctly shutdown these simultaneous threads

Tags: java, multithreading

As in the subject do I correctly shutdown these simultaneous threads?

I assigned a volatile field and check it repeatedly in while loop.

**Is there alternative way to do it**(like using synchronize or wait() method), please show me.

**EDIT** I edited code. Is there any way of checking if Thread is alive by different method thatn isAlive();?
Perhaps:

```
boolean isAlive(){
    return running;
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Wat extends Thread {
    private char c;
    private int interv;
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    Object synchObj;

    public Wat(char c, int interv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.interv = interv;
        synchObj = new Object();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            synchronized (synchObj) {
                try {
                    showChar(c);
                    synchObj.wait(interv * 100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public synchronized static void showChar(char c) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        running = false;
        synchronized (synchObj) {
            synchObj.notify();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Wat w1 = new Wat('A', 3);
        Wat w2 = new Wat('B', 4);
        Wat w3 = new Wat('C', 5);
        w1.start();
        w2.start();
        w3.start();
        Object[] options = { "Shutdown A", "Shutdown B", "Shutdown C" };
        int option;
        while (w1.isAlive() || w2.isAlive() || w3.isAlive()) {
            option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "Which one would you like to shut?", "Threads",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);
            switch (option) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                w1.shutdown();
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                w2.shutdown();
                break;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                w3.shutdown();
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a start, don't do this `catch (InterruptedException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: There is a small chance that the threads will still be alive when you check its status.  You might need to wait a short amount of time before checking.

Comment: @artbristol Instead he could wrap it in an `AssertionError` as it should never happen.

Comment: Is there any way doing it perhaps by different method?

Comment: Calls to most Swing methods must be done on the [AWT Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) - please put the body of the `while` into a `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { public void run() { ... } } );`

Comment: 1. **Don't extend Thread**, instantiate with `Runnable`. 2. **Use the built-in interruption mechanism** instead of ignoring it the way you do now. 3. To reliably detect thread state, call `Thread.getState`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will probably work fine, but the Thread.sleep is not very elegant. I would do something along these lines, calling the shutdown() method to quit the thread

```
 Object synchObj = new Object();

 public void run() {
    while (running) {
      synchronized (synchObj) {
         try {
            System.out.println(new Date());
            synchObj.wait(5000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             // error handling
         }
      }
    }
 }

 public void shutdown() {
    running = false;
    synchronized (synchObj) {
        synchObj.notify();
    }
 }


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
        IOException {
    ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
    test.start();
    BufferedReader tReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    tReader.readLine();
    test.shutdown();
}
```

**EDIT** added test code

Comment: I have tried. http://wklej.org/id/863495/ I wanted make threads will write a char repeatedly.

Comment: how about synchObj.wait(timeout)?

Comment: Could you look at my edit please. I think it is closer I would like to get, but I get exceptions. I would like to Threads stop immeadatly after shutdown option,

Comment: Thank you man!!! But i still need use Thread.wait(1) in the end of main method otherwise I have to click the Dialog 4 not 3 times(there are 3 threads) I have made edit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are closing the threads correctly. The only comment is that you are breaking the encupsulation here because the flag `running` is accessed directly. I'd recommend you to add method `shutdown()` that changes this flag to `false`.

EDIT.

I have just noticed that you are calling `sleep()` inside the loop. This is indeed bad practice in most cases. You should probably call `wait(timeout)`. In this case your `shutdown()` method will change the flag to `false` and then call `notify()` on same monitor. This will cause your thread to exit immediately.

Comment: Thank you! Is there alternative way to do it?

Comment: I do not understand. I have made edit to the code but I get:
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Answer (score 0):

It seems the program is perfect, uses volatile boolean variable and makes it false.

synchronized need only multi thread access. instead of sleep you can use wait, it has a object access rather than static sleep, also any time you can interrupt the waiting.